# Running Jenkins with apache at /jenkins

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, jenkins, proxypass

I need to have access at the `/jenkins` path to the **Jenkins** server.

This is what I have now in my apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080
```

When I go to `example.com/jenkins`, 
I get redirected to `example.com/login?from=%2F`, 
instead of the expected `exmaple.com/jenkins/login?from=%2F`.

So is it possible *with **apache*** to make all the requests coming from my **Jenkins** server, be of the form `example.com/jenkins/*` instead of `example.com/*`?

P.S.: I know it would be a far better practice create a new server, named something like `jenkins.example.com`, but that's not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: If you are being "redirected" then there would seem to be _something else_ doing that, not your proxy code?

Comment: Yes, the login request is the normal behavior expected from the Jenkins server, which goes to `/login?from=%2F`. But I want it to go to `/jenkins/login?from=%2F`. I'm not sure this is possible with apache. It could be that I cann only handle this from within the Jenkins server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an option for configuring the Jenkins URL, inside Jenkins itself: [Jenkins website root path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089610/1410452).

Also, I have found the apache configuration documentation, in the Jenkins Wiki:
 [Running Jenkins behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).

**EDIT**:

I managed to achieve running the **Jenkins** server at `http://example.com/jenkins` like this:

- on my local machine, by adding to the `JENKINS_ARGS` variable, the `--prefix=/jenkins` attribute, in `/etc/default/jenkins` file, and then restarting the Jenkins service. (soruce: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32071886/1410452))
- on my docker image, by adding `--prefix=/jenkins` at the end of the `run` command: `docker run --name Jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins --prefix=/jenkins`

And here is my **apache** configuration entry for **Jenkins**:

```
ProxyPass        /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyRequests    Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Source: [Running Jenkins behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache)

Answer (score 1):

I tested such a setup on a dummy index.html.

```
ProxyPass "/jenkins" http://192.168.0.99
ProxyPassReverse "/jenkins" http://192.168.0.99
```

Like this it worked as expected, when I opened http://example.com/jenkins I got redirected to the index.html at http://192.168.0.99.

You should have a look in your htdocs root of jenkins. If there is a redirect like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/login?from=%2F">` then it will redirect to *example.com/login?from=%2F*. 
If you change the redirect to relative path with leading `.`, it will redirect correctly:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=./login?from=%2F">
```

Like this it would correctly redirect to *example.com/jenkins/login?from=%2F*